# Realtime data from firestore flutter not working

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I was following this tutorial on how to get realtime updates from flutter firestore, 
https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-use-cloud-firestore-in-flutter-9ea80593ca40 and I scrolled down to **Listen For Realtime Updates** section and when I followed the tutorial, this is what I came up with,

```
  String name = 'name here';
  String children = 'children here';
  String docId = '0';

  @override
  void initState() {
    getUsers();
    super.initState();
  }

  getUsers() async {
    final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    final User? user = auth.currentUser;
    final uid = user!.uid;

    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("userNames")
        .where("uid", isEqualTo: uid)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((result) {
      result.docs.forEach((result) {
        print(result["firstName"]);
        print(result["children"].toString());
        name = result["firstName"];
        children = result["children"].toString();
      });
    });
  }
```

When I print the values to the console they update in realtime, but when I put them in variables and concatenate them into a Text widget like this:

```
Text('Children: $children'), //It does not update in realtime.
```

For instance, if in my document if I have `children: 3` and I display in in my app, it shows 3, but when I manually change it, it does not update in realtime, I have to press hot reload. Another issue is that I have to initialize the variable before using them in the function, up ahead in the first 3 lines of code. When I hot restart, it shows the values of what I use to initialize them. For where it should show children, it says 'children here' and for where the name is, it puts 'name here', only when I hot reload the page, do the actual firestore values get inputed into them and show data from the firestore database. If there is a solution to any of these problems, I would much prefer an answer in code instead of a link or a brief explanation, I spend hours before I find a piece of code that utilizes the explanation. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the data is loaded asynchronously, the data isn't available when Flutter first paints your `Text` widget. You'll need to tell Flutter that it has to repaint the UI when the data is available.

There are two common ways to do this:

- Put the `children` variable in the state of your widget by calling `setState()`. This will tell Flutter to repaint the widget, and your text will then show the value.
- You can also use a `StreamBuilder` widget, which does the above too - but it also handles all kinds of error states automatically.

I recommend reading about [stateful widgets and `setState`](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/interactive#stateful-and-stateless-widgets) and about the [`StreamBuilder` class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html) to learn more.

Comment: I dont know who would answer firebase questions if you weren't on stack overflow

Answer (score 1):

I use snapshots().listen() to listen to change. Then I use ValueNotifier to notify the UI.

```
final itemsNotifier = ValueNotifier<List<Item>>([]);

    FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("userNames")
    .where("uid", isEqualTo: uid)
    .snapshots()
    .listen((event) {
    itemsNotifier.value = event.docs
        .map((doc) => Item.fromSnapshot(
            doc as DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>))
        .toList();
   itemsNotifier.notifyListeners();
  });
```